# Android: cannot connect to Windows 10, while it works to Windows 7 from same device through same box

Tags: wireless-networking, android, connection, smb

On my phone I'm using `File Manager +`, `Remote` option, to connect to my 2 desktops, both linked to the same box via Ethernet cable.

The first desktop uses Window 7, and all works fine.
The other one uses Windows 10, and when trying to `Add remote`, after typing (myName) and (myPassword) I get an error message:
`Cannot connect to (thisDesktopIPaddress) with user (myName)`

This happens regardless I choose `SMB` and type the IP address, or I choose `Network`, which automatically detects the presence of my desktop (displaying its name) and presets the correct IP-address.

Note: I have already set the needed SMB 1 option (not default with Windows 10), so the desktop correctly recognizes itself in the `Network` area in Windows Explorer.

So what might be the problem?

Comment: Is the network connection set to "private" on the Windows 10 machine? How about the Windows 10 firewall. Does it allow incoming/outgoing SMB traffic?

Comment: @Robert. Yes, the network connection is set to "private". But it's the same on the other (Win 7) machine. In the firewall, about SMB traffic, I found only 3 rules, whose 1 was unset: I set it, but it keeps refuse to connect.